# What defines the prefix in a rails route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

When I run `rails routes` it returns the following.

```
solves POST     /solves(.:format)             solves#create
new_solf GET    /solves/new(.:format)         solves#new
edit_solf GET   /solves/:id/edit(.:format)    solves#edit
solf GET        /solves/:id(.:format)         solves#show
PATCH           /solves/:id(.:format)         solves#update
PUT             /solves/:id(.:format)         solves#update
DELETE          /solves/:id(.:format)         solves#destroy
```

Obviously this isn't the whole thing, but it's all that's pertinent.

As you can see, the prefix for "new" and "edit" looks a little strange. I'm not entirely sure what happened, but I believe I misspelled "solve" when creating my scaffolding, as I had "solf" in my controller as well. I've replaced all that, I can't find any other references to "solf" in any of my files, and I've dumped and reloaded my database.

The actual routes are correct, but the prefix's aren't. What determines these, and how can I fix this?

Comment: What is the name of the model associated with "solves," and what is the expected result? By convention, Rails resources are *nouns*, but "solve" is a verb. It doesn't make sense to "show solves" or "create a solve."

Comment: I have marked this as a duplicate, but I wanted to mention the cause of the problem: Rails has a set of built-in inflections that tell it how to pluralize/singularize most nouns. You can see the inflection rule that was applied to your route name [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/9e352e38bdd52a06c06d2de88c155b84b9f18ca1/activesupport/lib/active_support/inflections.rb#L22). It looks like it was written with words like "half" ("halves"), "self" ("selves"), and "scarf" ("scarves"). Since "solves" isn't a noun, it's not surprising Rails didn't know how to inflect it.

Comment: Consider renaming it to "solution(s)" instead?

Comment: It has to do with Rubik's cube Solves, where a Solve is a collection of both a time and a status.